# Dynamodb - Is it possible to get multiple items sorted by an attirbute?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Considering my Users table schema looks like this:

```
{"_id": "6107e680432d016dea6c4124",  "age": 55,  "created_at": "2021-08-02T12:35:12.040Z", "gender": 1, "is_checked": true, "language": "en" }
{"_id": "6107d6f0d7b68252d46b0163",  "age": 20,  "created_at": "2021-07-01T12:35:12.040Z", "gender": 2, "is_checked": true, "language": "en" }
....
```

- "_id" is the primary key

How can I scan ( or query ) the table and get items ordered by "created_at"?

SQL equivalent would be:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age > 18 ORDER BY created_at DESC

I read many docs but it seems impossible to achive sorting with scan ( or even query ).

"scan" does not support sorting, "query" can sort, but it's useless since Primary Key only returns a single item.

I can get all records to client-side and sort there, but it sounds ridiculous. ( What if there are  100k items? )

I cant understand how such a popular tool can not achive the bare minimum of a list operation.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. I can change key structure, table schema etc. But there must be a way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not up to date with DynamoDB, but you may want to look at secondary indexes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Answer (score 1):

> "query" can sort, but it's useless since Primary Key only returns a single item.

DynamoDB is not a database where you load data, invent a query, run it, and expect it to return optimized results.

DynamoDB is a database where you define your access patterns, construct your data model and secondary indexes appropriate for them (taking into account your particular scaling concerns), and then you can easily achieve reliable low-latency and massively scalable performance (with serverless operation).

So you want to track some users and issue ad hoc queries about them. What's your scale? How many users? How many queries per second? What's your p99 performance requirement? If the answer is not that many users, not that many queries, and low latency is nice but not required, then it's a great relational database use case.

If your scale is millions of users, thousands of queries per second, and/or you need sorted answers in something like 100ms or less, a relational database is going to show real scaling problems.

So how do you do this in DynamoDB? You construct your data model to match the access patterns. You want so sort results by something. For this DynamoDB has a sort key. Create a GSI with `created_at` as the sort key and any singular value for the partition key (so they're all in the same item collection) and you can do a query sorted by timestamp against that index.

If you're updating more than 1,000 items per second, you will want to "write shard" and have multiple PK values (each of which will add 1,000 items per second to the throughput).

Comment: I think (?) I followed your instructions and created a GSI having a primary key that "covers" all of the items in the table. And for the sort key I entered "created_at". Now  I get can all users ordered by created_at asc / desc. However, I can't seem to understand how is this different than a scan which scans every record. With primary key being the same for all items, a query also runs through every item in the database. It would be great if you can share your ideas if this a bad approach or not. (Although I have no other choice )

Comment: Do you truly want ALL the items returned? Then they’re roughly equivalent. But usually people want the last 10 or first 10, and then paginate. Think of DyDB as supporting user apps. You never give the user 100,000 items at a time.

Comment: Actually max 1k items will be listed on the frontend. However, sorting must be done on all items on the table since there's no way to know which one of the "created_at"s falls in top 1k records. I saw another approach where they set the primary key of the GSI to only the date part of the created_at like "20220524" which will greatly reduce the size of the GSI, but then you're confined to users in last 24 hours. Maybe  increasing 24hours to a week may be more efficient but still confining.

Comment: It's odd with customer-facing websites to list 1,000 items. You can't view your last 1,000 Amazon orders without paging, or Instagram posts or Netflix shows or whatever. Is someone really going to review all 1,000? Remember, you have to pay by content size returned. Then, I don't see why would sharding the PK to use different date values would reduce the size of the GSI. All values would be in the GSI, just under different PK values, which makes "get last X many" a harder query to write cuz it crosses PKs.